# React Native - Setting item width according to the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I want 3 items to appear in each row and I want their size to be adjusted according to the screen itself, how can I do this?

I tried giving justifyContent to the flatlist columnWrapperStyle prop but the display turned out to be ridiculous

```
const renderSearchItem = ({
    item: { id, type, title, original_title, poster },
}) => (
    <Item
        id={id}
        type={type}
        title={title == null ? original_title : title}
        poster={poster}
        navigation={navigation}
        style={{ width: 115, height: 175 }}
    />
);

<FlatList
    data={data?.datas}
    renderItem={renderSearchItem}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    key={search}
    numColumns={3}
    onEndReachedThreshold={1}
    onEndReached={() => {
        fetchMore({
            variables: {
                search,
                offset: data?.datas?.length + 18,
            },
            updateQuery: (
                previousResult,
                { fetchMoreResult }
            ) => {
                if (
                    !fetchMoreResult ||
                    fetchMoreResult?.datas?.length === 0
                ) {
                    return previousResult;
                }

                return {
                    datas: previousResult?.datas?.concat(
                        fetchMoreResult?.datas
                    ),
                };
            },
        });
    }}
    ListHeaderComponent={headerComponent()}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
/>
```

Comment: Try to use width: 115, height: 175 with % like width: "30%" for example

Comment: unfortunately that didn't help :(

Comment: Since the item component is an image, the images are not given percentage width and height, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can get screen's width from Dimensions.

```
const width = Dimensions.get('screen').width
```

this will be the whatever the size of width the application running on.

Comment: I divided this width by 3 and gave the width to the picture, but it didn't work, what will it do for me?

Comment: @MehmetCOŞKUN okay can you share the "Item" component?

Comment: I posted the component as an answer.

Comment: the problem is most likely the TouchableHighlight's container, try removing alignItems and see how it looks

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function Item(props) {
const { id, type, title, poster, navigation, style } = props;

return (
    <TouchableHighlight
        style={styles.container}
        onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate(
                type == 'movie' ? 'MovieDetail' : 'SeriesDetail',
                {
                    id,
                    title: title == null ? original_title : title,
                }
            )
        }
    >
        <Image
            style={[{ ...style }, { borderRadius: 5 }]}
            source={{ uri: poster }}
        />
    </TouchableHighlight>
);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 18,
    marginLeft: 6,
},
});
```